# detect environment type (production, development or staging) in Silex

Tags: php, symfony, development-environment, production-environment, silex

I'm using the micro framework Silex, I need to detect the type of environment at runtime inside a given script. That means, detect if it's **dev**, **prod** or **staging**.

Comment: I do mine using a configuration file that lives on each machine that git isnt tracking.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary; behaviour should be controlled by configuration, not the label you attach to it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have experience with Silex but I always use environment variables for this. Then in your application you can get the current environment with:

```
getenv('ENVIRONMENT')
```

Answer (score 3):

Silex by itself doesn't have environments, only has a *debug mode*. In order to know if your application is in debug mode you have the `$app['debug']` variable.

Having said that nothing prevents you to create your own *environment* variable in, let's say `$app['env']` (yes very original...). So everywhere you need to know which environment are you running you can use the `$app['env']` variable.

In order to initialize this variable and following the [silex skeleton](https://packagist.org/packages/fabpot/silex-skeleton) you can have (in the web folder, your *DocumentRoot*) an `index.php`, `index_dev.php`, `index_stg.php` where you set the `$app['env']` accordingly before calling `$app->run()`.

Or you can use the technique explained by @WimMostmans and use a real environment variable :-)

Comment: Thanks, this solution would work for frontcontroller but i'm wondering how it would work on commands ?

Comment: You should set an argument for commands (--env) wich defaults to the environtment you want.